# Exception in destructor - UB or "may result in UB"?

Tags: c++, exception, destructor, undefined-behavior

I know it's a very common topic but I haven't been able to find the answer to **my specific question**.

Everyone knows throwing (and not handling) exceptions in destructors is a bad idea and you shouldn't do it but every SO answer/online article I've seen either simply said "don't do it" or it used the phrase "it **MAY RESULT** in UB" (emphasis mine). And that's the gist of my question - is an unhandled exception thrown in a destructor **always UB** or is that not a guarantee - for instance, does it depend on what else happens in the code before/after, are there any other conditions? Are there any situations in which an unhandled exception in destructor will result in a **well-defined** behavior?

Comment: There is no UB as far as I know. But it is likely to call `std::terminate` in a lot of circumstances.

Comment: ["used by some libraries, such as SOCI and Galera 3, which rely on the ability of the destructors of nameless temporaries to throw exceptions..."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) or this one: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_success/%7Escope_success

Comment: Exceptions thrown from a destructor never cause UB, but may result in calls to `std::terminate` depending on the context of the destructor call (if the exception escapes the destructor). However, the C++ standard library and probably many other libraries as well, require that user types supplied to them never throw from their destructor (meaning exception escaping the destructor). Violating such preconditions also is effectively UB.

Comment: @user17732522   If an element of a standard container throws from a destructor, it can affect ability of operations on the container to provide required exception safety AND performance guarantees.  For example, `std::vector::erase()` is required to not throw an exception which is difficult/costly to achieve if that operation must be implemented to properly handle an element's destructor throwing.   IIRC, that's part of the reason that recent standards specify that destructors should not propagate exceptions.